# UITableView sections from JSON data

Tags: iphone, json, uitableview

I have JSON data like this:

```
[{"id":"3","name":"jason"},{"id":"4","name":"karen"}]
```

I want to build a table view with a section for each pair [id, name]. The section title should be the *id* value, the only cell for each section should be the *name* value.

How can I parse the JSON data into an array and use [array count] in order to determine how many section have to be displayed?

Thanks very much..

forgive my bad English!

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wizard for my editor!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the `UITableViewDatasource` following methods :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [JSONArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    return 1;
}
```

To set the section's title value :

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[JSONArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"id"];
}
```

To set your cell's value implement `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.text = [[JSONArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"name"]; // set the cell's text here
    }
    return cell;
}
```

For reference check [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) and [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this project. Its a framework to work with JSON:
https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

A tutorial for this framework can be found at:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html

The framework adds a category to NSString. With that category you can parse JSON data into a NSArray (a list of objects as for your example) or a NSDictionary (some object or structure):

```
#import "JSON.h"
...
NSString jsonString = //get your JSON from somewhere
NSArray * array = [jsonString JSONValue];
```

I hope I could give you an impression, what to do in order to achieve your goal. Further information is in the tutorial of the JSON project or in the tutorial mentioned.

How to build a table from your JSON Array is in the answer: [UITableView sections from JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885220/about-uitableview-section/7885398#7885398)